# Is there a way to see that every solution of $ y^{r_1}-1=cy^{r_2}$ is constant without differentiating?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a positive smooth function, satisfying the equation $$ y^{r_1}-1=cy^{r_2},$$

where $c,r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants, $r_1,c \neq 0$.

Is there a way to prove that $y$ must be constant without using derivatives?

(Here is an approach which does use derivatives:)

By differentiating, we get

$$ r_1y^{r_1-1}y'=cr_2y^{r_2-1}y'.$$

Suppose by contradiction there exist a point $x$, where $y'(x) \neq 0$. Then $y' \neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of $x$. Now, at every point where $y' \neq 0$, we get  $ r_1y^{r_1-1}=cr_2y^{r_2-1} \Rightarrow y^{r_1-r_2}=c\frac{r_2}{r_1}$. So, if $r_1 \neq r_2$ $y$ is constant. Otherwise, $c=1$, and the original equation becomes $y^{r_1}-1=y^{r_1}$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, $y$ is constant in a neighbourhood of $x$, so $y'(x)=0$.

Comment: Is $y$ positive or do we take $y^{r_1}=e^{r_1 \text{Log}(y)}$ with $\text{Log}$ indicating the principal value?

Comment: $y$ is positive.

Comment: Since the curves $z = y^{r_{1}} - 1$ and $z = cy^{r_{2}}$ are real-analytic and not identical (different limiting behavior as $y \searrow 0$), their intersection is discrete. I suspect it's possible to get lower-tech, hence the comment rather than an answer.

Comment: If $r_1=c=0$ then $y$ can be anything.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks.Your idea is very cool. However, I am not sure about some details; 1) Does your proof assume $y$ is an analytic function? 2) Even if this is so, $y^{r_1}$ does not need to be analytic at zero, right? (for instance take $\sqrt y$. Is it trivial to see $y^r$ is analytic outside zero? If so, I guess this does settles the matter since this one point of singularity does not matter.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks, you are right. I think this is the only case where there is a problem. I added some details to address this issue.

Comment: Yes, the argument presumes power functions are real-analytic on $(0, \infty)$. Admittedly, assuming a local power series representation at each point may be "worse" than using derivatives....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x)=-0.25x^5+x^4-1$$
This fnction has two positive roots, as can bee seen, since:

- $f(0)=-1<0$,
- $f(2)=7>0$,
- $f(4)=-1<0$ and
- $f$ is continuous

Let $x_1,x_2$ be these roots and let:
$$y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x_1 & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\x_2 &  x\in\mathbb{Q}&\end{array}\right.$$

Now, it is clear that, for $r_1=4$, $r_2=5$ and $c=\frac{1}{4}$ we have:
$$y^{r_1}-1=cy^{r_2}$$

Also $y>0$.

So, smoothness is needed as a hypothesis, as we found a non-smooth $y$ that is not constant and, yet, satisfies the given equality.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Since there is a function $y$ which is not smooth  and satisfies all the other requierements requested but not the requested result (being constant), it does follow that one cannot prove that $y$ is constant without the hypothesis that $y$ is smooth. For, if one could prove $y$ is constant while not being smooth, then this counterexample should not exist.

P.S. Since $y$ in this example is not even continuous, I see that it might be continuosness a minimal hypothesis, but, in the question, smoothness and not continuity is mentioned.

Comment: The OP isn't asking whether smoothness is a necessary hypothesis. Rather, the OP seeks a proof in which no differentiation is needed.

Comment: Should such a proof exist, wouldn't then $y$ be a counter-example to it and hence, turning it to a non-valid proof?

P.S. With smooth, I mean - and understand it as - $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider the following (silly) Theorem: The function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=1$ is a constant function. It's a trivial result, no? Now consider the following proof: Since $f$ is a polynomial function, then it is differentiable, and taking the derivative, we get $f'(x)=0,$ so $f$ is constant.

Comment: But there exists no fuction $f$ such that $f(x)=1$ and $f$ is not constant, so there is no such counter-example - maybe the result being too trivial prevents me from seeing your point. In our case, should one be able to prove that $y$ is constant without using smoothness, it would mean that there may be non-smooth functions that satisfy both the given equation and the rest conditions and are constant. But, finding a non-smooth function that does so means... Well, writing this I think I see what you mean. If such a function exists then, there may be a proof that does not use smoothness. Right?

Comment: Again, I don't think the OP wants to avoid using smoothness. Rather, the OP wants a proof without taking the derivative of $y.$

Comment: But nut using the derivative of $y$ means that it is not a neede hypothesis - and hence, smoothness isn't, either - isn't it so?

Comment: Not really. For example, one could use the result (as suggested in the comments above) that the graphs of distinct real-analytic functions have discrete intersections. See also the approach in the other answer (though I'm unfamiliar with Vandermonde determinants, so I don't know whether that one is viable).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62276/discussion-between---and-cameron-buie).

Answer (score 0):

A try for a (not simple...) solution. First, I suppose that $r_1r_2c\not =0$, and in addition that $r_1\not=r_2$. Let $F(t)=1+ct^{r_1}-t^{r_2}$. Suppose that there exist an interval $I=[a,b]$, with $0<a<b$ such that $F(t)=0$ for all $t$ in $I$. Choose  $\alpha$ and a $\beta>0$ such that $\log a<\alpha<\alpha+\beta<\alpha+2\beta<\log b$. Put $t_k=\exp(\alpha)\exp(k\beta)$ for $k=0,1,2$. Then $F(t_k)=0$ and the linear system $x_1+x_2 \exp(r_1\beta)^k+x_3\exp(r_2\beta)^k=0$ $k=0,1,2$ has a non trivial solution $(1, c\exp(r_1\alpha), -\exp(r_2\alpha))$. Hence the determinant of the system must be $0$ (it is a Vandermonde  determinant). We get that $(\exp(r_1\beta)-1)(\exp(r_2\beta)-1)(\exp(r_1\beta)-\exp(r_2\beta))=0$, a contradiction.

Now your function $y(x)$ is such that $F(y(x))=0$. If your continuous $y$ is not constant, then its range is a non trivial  interval, contradiction by the above. It remains to look at the excluded cases.